# Frase "amigo é amigo, fdp é fdp" em inglês

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução

Tô procurando uma frase inglesa para traduzir *"amigo é amigo, fdp é fdp"*. Já entendi as palavras e o sentido, mas mesmo como falante nativo de inglês, não consigo achar uma expressão igual.

Comment: I don't recognize this as a saying.  At least not in pt-BR.  You can, therefore, translate it any way you like.  e.g. A friend is a friend and a bitch/foe/jerk/whatever is a bitch/foe/jerk/whatever.

Comment: You must remember this, a friend is still a friend, a sob is just a sob...

Comment: Francamente não sei que fazer perante este tipo de pergunta. Eu acho que perguntas do tipo "como se diz isto em inglês?" não são sobre língua portuguesa. No [What topics can I ask about here?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) diz-se, que não somos um serviço de tradução. Mas [nesta discussão no meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/well-allow-translations-to-and-from-which-languages/134#134) defende-se a possibilidade de traduções para inglês, e há já aqui perguntas que são exatamente isso. Eu acho que deveríamos repensar este assunto >>

Comment: >> e adotar uma posição coerente.

Comment: Entretanto, Mark, se fores ao ELU e disseres, há esta frase em português que significa isto assim e assim, qual é a melhor maneira de exprimir isto em inglês, ou coisa assim, terás lá muito mais gente para te ajudar.

Comment: Falei q entendi as palavras e o sentido. Nao precisei de uma traducao literal. Eh uma expressao q os meus amigos brasileiros usam o tempo tudo e eu estava procurando uma frase coloquial em ingles. Da mesma forma q 'a ultima gota' nao eh 'the last drop' em ingles, ao contrario eh 'the last straw'.

Comment: Mark, se quisesses saber o significado da frase, faria todo o sentido perguntar aqui. Mas precisamente porque já sabes o que a frase significa e o que pretendes é uma frase equivalente em inglês é que eu digo que faria sentido perguntar isto no [English Language SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions). Terias naturalmente de lhes explicar o que a frase significa.

Comment: @Jacinto o teu último comentário convenceu-me.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas eu acho que é importante revisitar [esta pergunta sobre traduções](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/well-allow-translations-to-and-from-which-languages), e adotar uma posição clara, e sermos coerentes.

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa ser literal, ex: *Mate is a mate, motherfucker is a motherfucker.*

Inglês é rico em siglas para frases, como OMG, LOL, etc. Há alguma para "motherfucker", "son of a bitch", ou outras? Poderia ser usada nessa tradução.